# PrimeNg is not working with .scss file

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I have tried to setup PrimeNg in to my Angular-CLI project. So I followed the steps like
`npm install primeng --save
npm install primeui --save`

I need a drop down, so I have added
 `import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/primeng';` in to my main module.ts file followed by `imports:[DropdownModule]`. 
Then styles added in to the .angular-cli.json file like 
`"../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.scss",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.scss"`. 
I used **.SCSS** file for styling. I have added dropdown in to my html 
`<p-dropdown [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity1"></p-dropdown>`
My issue is style is not reflected into the page and showing the following error when I click on the drop down.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

1 - First create a project with angular cli, using sass (or adjust an existing one, when using css-setup) with following command:

```
 - ng new project --style=scss
```

2 - Get the needed packages to work with PrimeNg

```
 - npm install primeng –-save
 - npm install font-awesome --save
```

3-  Adjust the **styles.scss**, by importing the needed css and scss

```
 -  @import 
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css", //is used by the style of ngprime
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css", // this is needed for the structural css
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.scss", // this is the scss file of one of the 16 free styles of ngprime.
```

4 - You can adjust scss variables in '../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.scss' if needed. The dropdown will be adjusted accordingly.

[Here you can find a the style of the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUenU.png)